# Nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected java.util.concurrent.RunnableScheduledFuture

Tags: java

I am getting the below exception while upgrading from java 8 to java 17.

If anyone is facing the below issue and have some solution , please post it.
Details stack trace is mentioned below

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-09-26 01:29:07 - o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: **Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.task.TaskExecutorMetricsAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected java.util.concurrent.RunnableScheduledFuture java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.decorateTask**(java.lang.Runnable,java.util.concurrent.RunnableScheduledFuture) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util.concurrent" to unnamed module @433defed
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:405)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:921)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292)
```

java 8 to java 17 upgradation

Comment: found the solution 
when you are running the application in local , put the below java options under Run as -->run configurations->arguments-->VM arguments


--add-opens java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
 --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED 
--add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED


for remote /server running in my case as we are using Kubernetes , in values.yaml file I have added below 

- name: JAVA_OPTS
    value: " --add-opens java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED"